# Change color of table according to the form value submitted

Tags: html, css, jsp, html-table

In my jsp page i am trying to change the color of rows depending on a form value i input.I want to change the color of a row when the value of my user column is changed.
for example if i change the column value of the user to false the color of that entire row should change to whatever the color i specify.
 I do not clearly understand as to how to do it

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>pharmacist id</th>
            <th>employee id</th>
            <th>firstname</th>
            <th>lastname</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>address</th>
            <th>phone</th>
            <th>salary</th>
            <th>User Availabilty</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="thepharmas" items="${Pharmacist_list}"> 

        <!-- set up a link for each pharmacist -->
        <c:url var="templink" value="PharmacistControllerServlet">
            <c:param name="command" value="LOAD"/>
            <c:param name="pharmacist_peid" value="${thepharmas.peid}"/>

        </c:url>
        <!-- link for delete pharmacist -->
        <c:url var="deletelink" value="PharmacistControllerServlet">
            <c:param name="command" value="DELETE"/>
            <c:param name="pharmacist_peid" value="${thepharmas.peid}"/>
            </c:url>
        <tr class="${thepharmas.user ? 'red_bg' : ''}">
        <td>${thepharmas.eid}</td>
        <td>${thepharmas.peid}</td>
        <td>${thepharmas.firstname}</td>
        <td>${thepharmas.lastname}</td>
        <td>${thepharmas.email}</td>
        <td>${thepharmas.address}</td>
        <td>${thepharmas.mobileNo}</td>
        <td>${thepharmas.basicSal}</td>
        <td>${thepharmas.user}</td>
        <td><a href="${templink}">Update</a>
            |
            <a href="${deletelink}"
            onclick="if(!(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this pharmacist?'))) return false">
            Delete</a>
        </td>

        </tr>

    </c:forEach>


    </table>
```

Once the value of the user column is changed. Depending on that user columns value i want to change the value of the entire row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this using jquery [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1v3xz9h8/)
html sample:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>no</td>
  <td>yes</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>yes</td>
  <td>yes</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and some css:

```
table{
  border:none;
}
td{
  border:none;
}
.red_bg{
 background:red;
 color:#fff;

}
```

and js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('table tr').each(function(){
     if($(this).children('td:nth-child(1)').text()=='no'){
       $(this).addClass('red_bg');
      }
    });    
});
```

Edit
you can try using if else statment
like

```
<tr style="${thepharmas.user ? 'background:red;' : ''}">
</tr>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193392/discussion-on-answer-by-moneer-kamal-change-color-of-table-according-to-the-form).